# Ionic Web Application - Back Navigation makes page blank (White Screen)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4

I have created the ionic web application for mobile browser using

```
ionic platform add browser
ionic build browser
```

then copy the www folder and hosted it into the PHP server.

Everything works fine but i have only one issue when the back pressed from the browser page goes blank (White screen). When i did ionic serve that time back navigation has no issue.
This problem only happen when i host it into Server. Is there any solution to avoid the blank screen ?

ionic version 4